# What is the permission ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER?

Tags: permissions

Some launcher apps uses `android.permission.ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER` permission.

What is this permission for?

Comment: Though the name suggests an Android core permission, no details on this can be found in official places (e.g. [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) or the [code at Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml)). Still, tons of apps use this permission. I always wonder how devs find out they might need it – guess they're the only ones able to answer your question.

Comment: Seems only specific to [Huawei devices](https://census.tsyrklevich.net/permissions/android.permission.ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER)

Comment: @AndrewT. saw that one, yes. But it mostly says census *detected* it there (strong indicator, though). Doesn't Huawei have its own namespace for perms, like others (Samsung e.g. uses `com.sec.android.*` – so I thought Huawei-specifics are covered by `com.huawei.android`, as that census list suggests as well)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Good guess, though: Digging a bit deeper at Census, I've figured what provides this permission. See my answer below for details.

Comment: this permission is used in microsoft arrow launcher and the weather is displaying in my lenovo device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew's guess was correct: According to [Android Census](https://census.tsyrklevich.net/content_providers/com.huawei.android.weather), this permission is declared by Huawei's own weather app (or rather the data provider behind it). The site further [shows it has been found on Huawei devices only](https://census.tsyrklevich.net/permissions/android.permission.ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER) (at least by them), covered by different protection levels (ranging from "normal" to "signature|system"), thus it cannot be even clearly said whether its declaration by some user app would have any effect at all.

---

For clarification: `com.huawei.android.weather` is a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), protecting access to its data via the `android.permission.ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER`. If an app requests that permission, it must be granted to it on install – which is done based on at least two conditions to be met: 1) Android knows of that permission (i.e. the app providing it is already installed), and 2) the protection level permits it. For "user-installed apps" that limits it to "normal" and "dangerous" [protection levels](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#protlevel). Now note the [second census link](https://census.tsyrklevich.net/permissions/android.permission.ACCESS_WEATHERCLOCK_PROVIDER): for some devices, this permission uses level "normal" (so it's available to user-apps), while on others it is "system|signature" (and thus *not* available to user-apps).